# Using two "And"s

Tags: grammaticality, and-and

Is the following (part of the) sentence correct grammatically?

> ... I will describe how my personal experiences **and** my
>   professional **and** academic background have prepared me to ...

Comment: If you are an English language learner rather than a native speaker or serious linguist, you might find our sister-site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com) to be a better fit for your questions than the current site, given that our charter here at ELU reads: “English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts.”**

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct. In general, it is fine to write A and (B and C) if B and C are grouped (both referring to *background*) as in your example. Another example is

> Put the bananas and the green and red peppers in the fridge.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, but because of its atypical construction, it is generally used to emphasize the conjunction of the separate elements. That is to say, the extra stop with an added conjunction emphasizes both the nature of the conjunction and helps restate the independence of each component part.